# I need to be able to clone a SOAPMessage object, but it doesn't implement Clonable. How can I do this?

Tags: java, apache, web-services, soap, cxf

I have a "skeleton" SOAPMessage object, which will be the starting point of other SOAPMessages. I want to be able to clone the base SOAPMessage, so I can then fill it with the information needed and send it, and do this every time I need to send a SOAPMessage.
How can I clone a SOAPMessage, since it doesn't implement Clonable?
I've been looking for other frameworks and found Apache CXF, which has a SoapMessage class that is Clonable. However, I can't use it because the WSDL I'm using is old-style (encoded, or something) and doesn't allow me to import the WSDL into Java classes...
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to clone it ? is there  no constructor or maybe a method like `message.setProperty()` ? what library are you using so we could look into documentation

Comment: Because I'll need to use it several times for different messages, so cloning the base message into a different object would allow me to edit its contents without messing with the original message. The library I'm using is the default javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage

Comment: What framework you are using to generate stub and all ?

Comment: @NaveenRamawat I'm creating it "by hand". I initialize a SOAPMessage and fill the headers, etc. So basically I just use javax.xml.soap

Comment: Trying to reinvent the wheel :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change `SOAPMessage` to string, and use this string as a source for new instance message.

Example below.

```
public static String messageToString(SOAPMessage soap) throws  SOAPException, IOException{
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    soap.writeTo(stream);
    String message = new String(stream.toByteArray(), "utf-8");
    return message;
}

public static SOAPMessage stringToMessage(String soap) throws IOException, SOAPException{
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(soap.getBytes());
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, inputStream);
    return soapMessage;
}

SOAPMessage sourceMessage; //some message to clone need to initiate it
SOAPMessage clonedMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
clonedMessage = stringToMessage(messageToString(sourceMessage));
```

Work for me.